# wordpress returns http error 500 on a fresh install

Tags: php

I have `centos7` machine running `MariaDB` and `phpMyAdmin` running properly. I set wordpress for testing running on this machine some months ago and everything was running fine, I finished my test and left the server running for other purposes. Today I needed to access the wordpress sandbox on that server again, but I couldn't. I get the http 500 error I mentioned. I extracted a new wordpress folder in `/var/www/html` with the same result. I confirmed that the database was running fine, and that the apache server is running properly, but I still get the http 500 error. I also tried to enable debug mode in `wp-config.php` and I don't get any errors there as well.

Where else can I check for errors?

edit:

Here are the error messages in my `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

```
[Mon Mar 11 15:59:14.482983 2019] [:error] [pid 21485] [client 10.0.0.140:49559] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Mar 11 15:59:14.483029 2019] [:error] [pid 21485] [client 10.0.0.140:49559] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/wordpress/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Check your Apache error logs. `\var\log\apache2`

Comment: This log does not exist. ``locate log | grep apache`` returns 0 results.

Comment: Do you use Apache? Or are you using NGINX or something else such as httpd or lighttpd? Unless you've configured it not to log, there will be a log somewhere for the webserver you are using.

Comment: If I recall correctly, I was following [this](https://www.unixmen.com/install-wordpress-centos-7-linux/) tutorial. It lists ``httpd`` service as apache. I got the same success screenshot as appearing in the tutorial.

Comment: OK, I looked into ``/var/log/httpd/error_log`` and I see there is an error ``Failed opening required `/var/www/html/wordpress/index.php` (include path=`.:/usr/share/pear:/user/share/share/php') is Unknown on line 0``

Comment: Can you post up the exact error as an edit to your question, making sure you use the markdown "code" tool so we can see the exact error in context.